# Pathfinding in mixed network

Tags: geopandas, python-3, networkx, pysal

I have three geopandas GeoDataFrame representing a road network, telecommunication wires and a set of network devices to be connected to the network. They are respectively depicted as yellow lines, blue lines and big colored dots in
[image: this picture].

All data are in the same geographic projection (EPSG 3857).

As you can see the device to connect can be near a road, a wire or both, but the networks doesn't precisely overlaps.

I suppose I have to build some sort of graph to compute a path between "Start point" and both "Endpoints". I have to "walk" the road to reach Endpoint 1 , while I can reach Endpoint 2 "by wire".

Howewer road network and wire network are two different set of geometries. How can I geometrically "merge" both networks? Is it necessary to build a graph?